# How to ask a http server present a http header field `Content-Length`?

Tags: http

I am testing the Last.fm api using row socket interface.
Now i noticed that some of api's http response have not contain a field `Content-Length` .
But I want to know is there a way to ask the server presenting it?
Because i can't take good care of this in my program elegantly.

Quoth the RFC:
 7.2.2 Length
 When an Entity-Body is included with a message, the length of that body may be determined in one of two ways. If a Content-Length header field is present, its value in bytes represents the length of the Entity-Body. Otherwise, the body length is determined by the closing of the connection by the server.

Comment: While sending request to the server you can mention that which type of data you want back.I think Content-type is the header that you need to send in request.

Comment: It is not about the Content-type , while using Last.fm api , add the uri param "format=json" , then the server while return content in json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right RFC to look at is RFC 7230 (Section 3.3.2).

And no, in HTTP/1.1 a client has to be able to process chunked encoding (which would be the only legitimate reason not to provide a Content-Length header field).